# Spark-Scala UDF custom transformations

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What would be the best way to determine rows that are in contention/violate specific rules?

I have a dataframe that represents a combination of store/item which could be sold. Here a store may have many items and a item may be in many stores. For example:

```
Row Store    Item       Price  Warehouse    Zone  Status
1, Store-1, Basketball, 5.99,   21,         Z1,    Active
2, Store-1, Football,   6.99,   21,         Z2,    Active
3, Store-2, Basketball  5.99,   21,         Z1,    Active
4, Store-1, Basketball  4.99,   22,         Z1,    Not-Active
```

The objective is to choose a Store/Item combination but sometimes there are many choices for a specific store/item combination. There are specific rules as to which combination to pick. All the listed transformations apply to all the rows in the dataframe but I only want to focus on the rows where there is contention. Here it would be 1 & 4.

There will be millions of rows in the dataframe. Most of the items in the dataframe are singletons (thus making the choice easy), but for some the selection becomes more difficult as the rules are tiered, i.e. compare the sourcing zone, compare the Status, compare the price, and if they are all equal choose the first one you encounter.

Looking for thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: are you asking if you should use udf to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

How about filter and reduce?

Say the dataframe is `df`, the combination is `store/item` and you have a function `compare` which determines the better one from two rows. The code would be

```
def compare(row1: Row, row2: Row): Row
df.filter($"Store" === store && $"Item" === item).reduce(compare)
```